# Recommendation sought for basic string difference algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that takes as arguments two strings, source and destination, and returns the steps required to transform the source string to the destination.  Something that takes Levenshtein distance one step farther.

E.g.,

Input: source "abc", dest "abbc"
Output: insert 'b' at position 1 in source

Input: source "abc", dest "ac"
Output: delete 'b' at position 1 in source

Thanks very much.

Comment: Sounds like homework--If so you should tag it, it's not like we won't answer.

Comment: Definitely not homework, it's for touch based word correction in my custom Symbian text box.

Comment: If you don't have Dan Gusfield's book, I highly recommend it. It really is the only definitive book on the subject.

Comment: Will check it out, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Strings-Trees-Sequences-Computational/dp/0521585198   but don't be put off by the "computational biology" bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the algorithm as shown on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), understand it and make the modifications that are necessary. I **does** solve your problem, you probably just didn't know it, and didn't record your answer along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the diff algorithms on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

Answer (score 0):

You might try going through first and lining up all the letters in pairs.  After you've paired as many as possible, the inserts and deletes should be obvious.

```
abcde
| /|
acbdd
```

So you remove the b & e and add a b & d

Remember the lines can't cross.

Comment: actually, your method won't guarantee an optimal solution. the most optimal solution may be to do the unintuitive and make to substitutions rather than one insert, for instance. it depends on how you weight the operations (insert and delete are usually very expensive). the well-known algorithms will take this into account. they will usually rely on a dynamic programming solution.

Comment: You are correct.  I was going under the assumption that this was a school assignment and simplicity would be more valuable than accuracy.  If you want accuracy, scan for the largest chunk that matches, then take what remains on either side of that chunk (for both strings) and recurse.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find a way to send it to an existing well-tested diff utility and use the results of that diff, e.g. diff -e or diff -n.